# How to read by multiple lines instead of line-by-line

Tags: bash, text-processing, html

I see that in my code I can modify a line if the entire code is based on that line.  Example: `<p class="example">this is an example Happy Holidays</p>`.  However if the `</p>` tag is located on a second line the code will pass that line.

What is the best way to detect until the line ends for certain tags?

Comment: 1) Text manipulation tools are not suitable for parsing HTML. 2) [Regular expressions are not suitable for parsing HTML.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) Based on 1) and 2): pick a dedicate HTML parser library and write a script which uses it. Otherwise you can play with setting the `RS` in `awk` to “>” or “</[^>]+>”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text utilities work on lines (text lines being (not too long) sequences of non-NUL characters terminated by a newline character). `awk` is the one standard utility that can be told to work on record separated by other things than newline characters, that's why `awk` talks of *records* instead of *lines*.

For instance, you could use `>` as the *record* separator. As in:

```
awk -v RS='>' ...
```

Another approach is to swap the character you want to use as the record separator (for other tools than `awk`) with the newline character:

```
... |
  tr '\n>' '>\n' |
  sed ... |
  other-text-utility... |
  tr '\n>' '>\n'
```

Those assume that the things you want to modify don't include nested HTML tags as they would start new records.

That is replace

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is: **do not use shell to parse XML**. Use a XML parser instead, e.g. one of the numerous for Perl: [XML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/XML-Parser-2.36/Parser.pm), [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm), or any other language. For HTML, [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.69/Parser.pm) is an option (if we stay with Perl).

If you want to use `bash`, you can play with the `read` built-in and a loop a bit.

Comment: As this question is tagged [tag:html], better suggest HTML parsers instead. Very few HTML documents are syntactically valid and XML parsers are picky on syntax errors by their nature.